# Compiling programs to OSX

Tags: osx, compiling

I have to decide between a MacBook Pro or an iMac.  I have a desktop with Ubuntu and I love it. I have experience with terminal and I install texlive, TeXstudio, Bluefish, Geogebra, wxMaxima, gnuplot and so on.

My question is: if I choose to replace my desktop by an iMac would it be possible to keep using those programs? I know that there are Mac OS X versions but sometimes they don't update frequently.

For example, the official TeXstudio webpage says:

> The OS X version is experimental. Since none of the currently active developers is using OS X, we cannot thoroughly test it. We do our best to also support OS X but be prepared that there may be some issues.

So, is it possible to compile the source code to obtain a version for OS X? Usually I compile these programs by myself. If I choose the MacBook I can keep my desktop (but it is not so new and widescreen like iMac 27").

Answer (score 4):

For Tex, I suggest you to have a look at http://www.tug.org/mactex/

For compiling Linux/Unix programs on OSX in general,  you can start with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), it might already have the recipes for the programs you want, if not you'll need it to setup a basic toolchains (gcc/make/etc.) for compiling/linking

Comment: Thanks. One more question: do you know if is it possible to install some programs using terminal, like in Linux. I know that there is a terminal but I don't know if it works so easy. For example, I use many times the `pdftk` program on terminal.

Comment: @Sigur, yes, you can install programs using terminal. Actually all programs install via homebrew is using terminal, just like apt-get/yum/etc. pdftk is quite tricky, you need to download server version http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.6-setup.pkg then follow this http://khkonsulting.com/2013/01/installing-pdftk-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/